# Accessibility of third-level domain and links to second-level domain

Tags: hyperlink, subdomain, accessibility, wcag2.0

I'm coding a third-level domain site (`accessible.example.com`) following WCAG 2.0 accessibility standards.

The final work will be submitted to an independent certification authority in order to obtain a mandatory certification, so I need to minimize errors on matching WCAG standards.

Is it safe to show in `accessible.example.com` pages links to `example.com` pages which have not accessible content?

Comment: Can you tell us what the "certification authority" is?

Comment: Do you ask if there’s a difference between linking to any external page (e.g., a Wikipedia article) and a page under the same second-level domain as your site? Or do you ask if linking to external (no matter under which domain), possibly inaccessible pages, is allowed?

Comment: None of the two. I'm guessing if a link on the second-level domain accessible page to a non accessible content page running on first-level domain is WCAG 2.0 compliant.